# Logging variables into a file in C

Tags: c, logging

I have quite a large project at work written in C (which I have little experience in) and I'm looking to create a log file when it is run that will log the value of variables (of all different data types) to a txt file.

It seems it is really not very straight forward with a language like C (for a beginner)

I'm trying to write a function to call throughout the code that will simply write values to a txt file with maybe a timestamp. It doesn't need to be clever or anything.

I found this [C logging](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-logger-in-c.html) example that works well for strings and integers but when I attempt to expand it for doubles it doesn't work.

Any help on how to go about this in an easy to understand way would be appreciated!

Thanks

Update:

The code extended for double data types from the link... just another switch case:

```
case 'f':
{
    e = va_arg( list, double );

    fprintf(fp,"%f", e);
    continue;
}
```

I then in my main function call it..

```
int main()
{
    double floating = 25.3;    
    LOG_PRINT("%f", floating);
}
```

The output to the file is 0.0000 instead though..

Comment: Can you provide an example of you calling the example you've shown above that fails? It looks like this example will work well, it may just be a minor issue with the format specifiers.

Comment: I used the %f format specifier... see my edit above.

Comment: What type is `e`?

Comment: In the code you're basing your modifications on, the declaration of `e` is `int e;` — so it is not surprising you're getting erroneous results.  You read a `double` into an `int`, throwing away any fractional information, and then lie to `printf()` and tell it you're passing a `double` when actually you pass an `int`.  Consider: `case 'f': { double d = va_arg(list, double); fprintf("fp, "%f, d); continue; }`.  Note, too, that you should have been getting `0.000000` since the default precision for `%f` is 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes good spot. The data type of `e` was set to `int`

I created a new variable of type `double` and used this instead.

```
double d;

case 'f':
{
    d = va_arg( list, double );

    fprintf(fp,"%f", d);
    continue;
}
```